# How to JOIN a group of tables in a database with similar name using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have a Database called db, and there are 100 tables in it called `ta_1` ... `ta_100` respectively. Each table has two columns `id(int)` and `val(int)`.

1. If I want to get the overall mean of val, what should I do?
2. If I want to get a table as a result with two column: tablename(String) and mean(float), what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes without saying that you should not have set up your database this way. There are a number of solutions, ranging from easy but mundane, to hard but useful.

At some point, you have to create a list of tables, and prepare a statement that merges them together. Copy&Past using a database view would be a good start:

```
create view GlobalView (
    tabname varchar(10),
    id int,
    val int)
as
   select 'ta_1', id, val from ta_1
UNION ALL
   select 'ta_2', id, val from ta_2
UNION ALL
   select 'ta_3', id, val from ta_3
UNION ALL
   .....
UNION ALL
   select 'ta_100', id, val from ta_100
```

Then, you can simply run the select:

```
select avg(1.0 * val) as mean
from GlobalView
```

The alternative would be to create a dynamic query that you can call either from an external program, or by using 'dynamic SQL'

Comment: I can use
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='databasename' to get the tablename list. Does there exist some way to loop through the list?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, and it's covered under a broad (too broad, perhaps) concept of 'Dynamic SQL'. MySQL support for Dynamic SQL is very limited, and you are likely to be better off creating the loop outside the query, and processing multiple SQL calls from your program, not from a single statement, or procedure.